# Correct Loop to use for Repeated Applications of /. Rule?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a $n\times n$ table (matrix). Let's just say $n=2$ but it is arbitrary. It has a smattering of indexed coefficients, see below for example.

```
table = {{a[1,2]c, a[1,1]x},{a[2,1],a[1,1]x^3}}
```

The point is that the indices on the coefficients `a[i,j]` do not depend on position in the table. I want to substitute each `a[i,j]` to something else, say

```
table /. a[i,j] -> t[i,j]a[i,j]
```

What is a good loop to accomplish this? It will have to loop through {i,n}, {j,n},..., so basically $n^2$ applications of `Rule`.

Comment: It's unclear. First, I guess that by `a[1,2]c` you mean `a[1,2]*c` (spaces matter!). Second, Rules are generally quite fast. Can you provide an actual example? Overall, this can be achieved in a number of ways, which efficiency depend on the particular application.

Comment: Does this work? `table /. a[i_, j_] :> t[i,j]a[i,j]`?

Comment: construct a list of all the rules and do a single replacement, eg. `table/. {a[1,2]->.., a[2,1]->.. , } `

Comment: Thanks March and George, both work nicely :).